# formData object not working with jquery AJAX post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, form-data

lets jump right into the code :

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('name', dogName);
formData.append('weight', dogWeight);
formData.append('activity', dogActivity);
formData.append('age', dogAge);
formData.append('file', document.getElementById("dogImg").files[0]);
console.log(formData);
```

Here I am appending some strings and one file object to the formData object in order to send all the information asynchronous to the server.

Right after that I have this jquery ajax request :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/foodoo/index.php?method=insertNewDog",
  data: JSON.stringify(formData),
  processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
  contentType: "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8",
  success: function(response){
     console.log(response);
  },
  error: function(){
  }
});
```

So here I am trying to POST the info to the server, on the server php file I have a simple print_r of the POST so I see what gets through and what not.

Unfortunately my response in the console.log(data) is empty.

Also if you check the HEADER in the Network tab you get the following empty output:

[image]

Success function gets called (just for clarification)

Comment: `JSON.stringify` only works with **plain** objects/arrays. `FormData` is not plain object. You have to pass [`FormData.getAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/getAll) instead of `FormData`

Comment: data: JSON.stringify(formData.getAll()) ? This results in Uncaught TypeError: formData.getAll is not a function

Comment: Then don't use `JSON.stringify` at all. Pass `formData` as is.

Comment: Okay, when I send it as it is - and then print_r the object in the php file and console.log it as a response i get a plain nothing ---- But the request Payload in the Header TAB in Network is now filled out with the send data

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you're sending an ajax request via jQuery and you want to send FormData you don't need to use `JSON.stringify` on this FormData. Also when you're sending file the content type must be `multipart/form-data` including `boundry` - something like this `multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary0BPm0koKA`

So to send FormData including some file via jQuery ajax you need to:

- Set `data` to the FormData without any modifications.
- Set `processData` to `false` (Lets you prevent jQuery from automatically transforming the data into a query string).
- Set the `contentType` to `false` (This is needed because otherwise jQuery will set it incorrectly).

Your request should look like this:

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('name', dogName);
// ... 
formData.append('file', document.getElementById("dogImg").files[0]);


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/foodoo/index.php?method=insertNewDog",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(errResponse) {
        console.log(errResponse);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have enhanced my code to yours and - unfortunately the response is plain empty :( and by empty i don't mean "null" or so, its just an empty  console.log

Comment: This is not working for me, look at my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35954488/how-to-grab-formdata-being-passed-from-ajax-to-nodejs?noredirect=1#comment59565110_35954488

Comment: formData.append('name', $("#idofinputfiled").val());

Comment: Thanks for this, I was looking all over for why I wasn't getting any data from my ajax request, but the trick was "Set data to the FormData without any modifications". I just had to append my extra fields to the formData object.

Answer (score 6):

if you did exactly as pervious anwswer and still not working 
dont worry `its working`

maybe `intelligence and quick wath`  are telling you its `not working`

[image]

but dont worry, look at `network tap` 
[image]

**its working**

hope this saves your time

Answer (score 2):

```
//For those who use plain javascript

var form = document.getElementById('registration-form'); //id of form
var formdata = new FormData(form);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST','form.php',true);
// xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
//if you have included the setRequestHeader remove that line as you need the 
// multipart/form-data as content type.
xhr.onload = function(){
 console.log(xhr.responseText);
}
xhr.send(formdata);
```

Comment: When answering, consider explaining the error/problem in the original question and how have you solved it. Don't forget that every question at StackOverflow is being viewed by a number of users and non-users to solve their similar problems. So for them to benefit from your answer, everyone would prefer to go through your explanation.

Comment: This answer save my day. !!!