# How to grab FormData being passed from AJAX to NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, file-upload

I am not sure where the code is wrong on the client or the server? It works if I do not send a FormData (req.body reads the info) but once I changed it to FormData since I am trying to send a picture along with some strings, I get a error 500 on the server side on the title.length console.log

Req.body with my current body-parser does not extract FormData being sent back by the AJAX JS Request...

This is my JS side:

```
var newProjectImage = $("#filebutton").get(0).files[0];
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('picture', newProjectImage);
formData.append('title', newProjectTitle.trim());
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/adminAddProject",
                    data: formData,
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    processData: false, // Don't process the files
                    contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request

                    success: function (data) {
                        if(data) {
                          alert("Product added");
                          successAddProject(data);  
                          enableAddProjectButtons();
                        } else {
                          alert("data does not exist ");
                          enableAddProjectButtons();
                        }
                        console.log("the data returned is " + JSON.stringify(data));
                    }
                });
```

This is the NodeJS side:

My app.js has these for body-parse:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Then the route is this:

```
router.post('/adminAddProject', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Called admin add " + JSON.stringify(req.body));

    if(req.cookies.token) {
console.log("Called admin token passes");
        if(req.body) {
            console.log("Called admin body is real ");
            var title;

            title = req.body.title;

            console.log("Called admin body is real " + title.length);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you extract POST data in Node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js)

Comment: No one explains it and I was looking specifically for a  file with data upload

Answer (score 0):

according to the docs for BodyParser - for multi-part data uploads you have to use different modules, I chose formidable.
https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm({
          uploadDir: '_dirname',
          keepExtensions: true
        });

    // parse a file upload
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) { })
```

Comment: Did it work? I'm having the same issue. Did you change something in the client side? Please let me know, your answer will be useful for me